# Android Kotlin: java.lang.IllegalStateException: title must not be null

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, illegalstateexception

I'm getting a IllegalStateException. Believe this is because my ProcessFragment.kt cannot identify id "title" for a TextView under fragment_process.xml.
How can I edit my code such that ProcessFragment.kt does not cause java.lang.IllegalStateException?

Thank you very much.

This is where the error occurs:

```
    title.text = initProcess()

}

private fun initProcess(): String {
    val python = Python.getInstance()
    val pythonFile = python.getModule("ProcessFile")
    return pythonFile.callAttr("Function1").toString()
}
```

ProcessFragment.kt

```
class ProcessFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        title.text = initProcess()

    }

    private fun initProcess(): String {
        val python = Python.getInstance()
        val pythonFile = python.getModule("ProcessFile")
        return pythonFile.callAttr("Function1").toString()
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_process, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ProcessFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            ProcessFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

fragment_process.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="view.ProcessFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: seems that `initProcess()` returns a null value

Comment: move `title.text = initProcess()` to `onViewCreated`

Comment: Works fine now, thank you.